# C++ curl how to use?

Tags: c++, curl

I am a beginner at C++ and would like to know how I include and use curl in my project. I am using https://github.com/dacap/pocketcpp on Windows. I searched the internet on how to include curl but I can't find any easy answers...

This is what I've got so far:

```
#include <curlpp/cURLpp.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Easy.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Options.hpp>


using namespace curlpp::options;

int main(int, char **)
{
    try
    {
        curlpp::Cleanup myCleanup;

        curlpp::Easy myRequest;

        myRequest.setOpt<Url>("https://google.com");
        myRequest.perform();
    }

    catch(curlpp::RuntimeError & e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    catch(curlpp::LogicError & e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
In file included from I:\C-CPP\workspace\backdoor.cpp:1:0:
I:\C-CPP\pocketcpp\MinGW\include/curlpp/cURLpp.hpp:33:10: fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory
 #include <curl/curl.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Did you add the correct header include paths?

Comment: Never heard of pocketcpp before, but this doesn't sound promising: "In next versions you'll be able to link multiple .cpp files and to use third party libraries" implying you can't use third party libraries now - and curl is a third party library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the pocketcpp link you provided:

> In next versions you'll be able to link multiple .cpp files and to use
>   third party libraries

So... yeah. It looks like with pocketcpp you can't do anything more than compile a single `cpp` file. Use a fully fledged IDE, like Visual Sudio, Visual Studio Code, Eclipse, Code::Blocks etc.

Comment: thank you, I'll take a look at how to use Visual Studio code

Comment: @Milan actually Visual Studio Code is not an IDE, it's an advanced texet editor and it requires external compiler and linker. Same is Eclipse, it's a bit tricky to use as C++ IDE at Windows. You'd better try the other two - Visual Studio or Code::Blocks.

Comment: @GoverNator they are all definitely IDEs. They are all applications creating an Integrated development environment. Weather some of them come with out-of-the-box compilers for one language or another or not at all doesn't affect that. And btw both Visual Studio and Code::Blocks require an "external" compiler. Visual Studio comes with Visual C++ compiler (aka MSVC++) but others can be configured, like clang and Code::Blocks offers gcc.

Comment: @GoverNator other than that I agree that Visual Studio is the easiest to use for beginners, working out of the box for C++ (if module is installed) without any configuration or extensions needed.

Comment: @bolov Thanks, I'm gonna use Visual Studio then

Comment: @bolov thanks for correction, I really meant "out-of-the-box", rather then external or built-in compiler.